# jQuery on scroll event: distinguish when is triggered by mouse

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, mouse, target

I am using:

```
$('.elem').on('scroll', function(e){
    //...
});
```

Is there a way to distinguish when it is triggered only **by mouse**?

I am using `slideUp()`, `slideDown()` programmatically that actually are triggering the event as well, so I need to find a way to filter it so I can detect when is triggered **only by mouse**

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `keyUp` event with it.

```
$('.elem').on('keyup scroll', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 38 || e.which == 40 || e.which == 33 || e.which == 34) {
    // key press happened using scroll.
  }
    //...
});
```

The `keyCode` values are for:

- `33`: Page Up
- `34`: Page Down
- `38`: Up
- `40`: Down

Comment: Also, key codes 33/34 are "Page Up"/"Page Down", and the spacebar (32) also scrolls the page as well... maybe you should just check if `e.type` is `keyup`.. rather than checking all the possible keycodes.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Agreed. Adding them.

Comment: @neoDev I don't understand you question. So this will make it like if you have pressed the keys, so that the scrolling is triggered by keypress.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Would you like to answer for the above comment? I might get annoyed in a few moments.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Let's see if the OP is able to understand. `:P`

Comment: @neoDev Don't use any key.

Comment: Now I am trying to use on 'weel', instead of 'scroll', what you think about it?

Comment: @neoDev Now I don't understand what does `scroll` mean. AFAIK, I would scroll a page using mousewheel, down, up, page down, page up. Right? If not mousewheel, then it should be by keypress, so I am using a condition. Very simple. Understood?

Comment: "If not mousewheel, then it should be by keypress"... NO. In my case it is triggered by jQuery slideUp(). No keys.

Comment: @neoDev Ah... I understand now. Well, no idea then. Be clear in what you say. `:)`

Comment: How do I have to update my question (my english is bad sorry)

Comment: @neoDev [Solution](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) is here... Enjoy... `:)`